# Sql query for retrieving member data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to make a payment to members on 1st may 2012 and i want to retrieve the data from the date between 1st april 2011 to 31st march 2012. How is it possible thru a query if i am a table (xyz) which maintains that on which date that person has become a member

Comment: `select * from xyz where memberAsOf between '2011-04-01' and '2012-03-31'`

Comment: This *is* as yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Also: you should use the proper ISO-8601 format to avoid any language- and dateformat-related problems. That format is `YYYYMMDD` (**no** dashes!) for SQL Server 2005 and `DATETIME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from xyz where datecoljoined between '2011-04-01' and '2012-03-31'
```

Complying with British settings:

```
select * from xyz where datecoljoined between '20110401' and '20120331'
```

Comment: Also: you should use the proper ISO-8601 format to avoid any language- and dateformat-related problems. That format is `YYYYMMDD` (**no** dashes!) for SQL Server 2005 and `DATETIME`. Your format with the dashes is **not safe** - it will e.g. **not work** if you use `SET LANGUAGE British` ..... (you'll get `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: I tried the following query select memberid,loan_acno,convert(varchar(12), DOS, 105) from mem_loan where DOS  between '01-04-2011' and '31-01-2012' but still it is returning me the data for the 23-05-2010 what is the bug ??

Comment: What's with asking for yyyy-mm-dd but using dd-mm-yyyy in queries? Use `WHERE DOS BETWEEN '20110401' and '20120331'` instead

Comment: yes but i am saving the data in table with ddmmyyyy format from the client

Comment: now will retrieving i am unable to find a query which can help me retrieve the data

Comment: above query told by you worked properly but only when my data is saved in the yyyy-mm-dd so i did a conversion

Comment: You're selecting out using a CONVERT(...) - and you are querying in another format. You should update your question to display what a few rows of data looks like. You can also use CONVERT(...) in your WHERE statement if you don't want to supply the dates in the same format as it is stored in the database.